# Show Hidden Form from anywhere in the application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a couple of forms.

Let's call them `indexForm`, `formOne`, `formTwo`, `formThree` and so on.

On `indexForm`, there's a button that goes to `formOne` and the button that does that has this bit of code:

```
private void buttonOpenFormOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formOne displayformOne = new formOne();
            displayformOne.Show();

            this.Hide();
        }
```

And to return to `indexForm`from `formOne`, I just do this:

```
private void buttonGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            indexForm displayIndexForm = new indexForm();
            displayIndexForm.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
```

Now this works perfectly if I'd gone from `indexForm` to `formOne`. So switching back to `indexForm` is a breeze. But if I went from `formOne` to `formTwo`, for example, the `indexForm` does not show up when the button is clicked.

My question is, how do I do it such that there's a way to globally return to `indexForm` from anywhere in the application or show the initially hidden `indexForm` from anywhere in the application?

Comment: @GrantWinney, how do I switch back to the original indexForm without creating a new instance and how do I show the hidden one?

Comment: @GrantWinney okay. So say I was in formTwo that I opened from formOne. How do I show hidden indexForm?

Comment: When you create a child form, set it's Parent property to the current form  `displayformOne.Parent = this;`   Then, the child form has access to the parent form and can reshow it.

Comment: do you know how many child forms there will be?

Comment: @RadioSpace Yes. The number of child forms is determinable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    if (frm.Name == "FormName")
    {
        frm.Show();
        frm.BringToFront();
    }

}
```